# use jqplot on multiple data sets

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have finally finished the functionality of the jqplot donut using data from an HTML table.

However, I now need to use this with many data sets to form graphs on different pages.

I would like to do this by have a variable that I can specify the file that contains the table and the ID for that table. However, currently I can only reuse the coding by copying and repeating it for every graph I need. This is very time consuming and not ideal, especially as I am likely going to need to make changes to them at some point. with over 100 graphs needed, it would be far better to only have to make changes to one bit of code.

```
$("#TableID").load( "tablefile.html #myTable tr:nth-child(4)", function() {
var tableVariable = '#TableID';

var GetData1 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').text());
var GetData2 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').text());
var GetData3 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)').text());
var GetData4 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4)').text());
var GetData5 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)').text());
var GetData6 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5)').text());
var GetData7 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)').text());
var GetData8 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)').text());
var GetData9 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').text());
var GetData10 = parseFloat($(tableVariable + ' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').text());

var PieChartS1 = [ ['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3], ['fourth', 4], ['fifth', 5] ];
var PieChartS2 = [['Tenth', 10], ['ninth', 9], ['eight', 8], ['seventh', 7], ['sixth', 6]];
var PieChartS3 = [['Tenth', GetData10], ['ninth', GetData9], ['eight', GetData8], ['seventh', GetData7], ['sixth', GetData6]];
var PieChartS4 = [ ['first', GetData1], ['second', GetData2], ['third', GetData3], ['fourth', GetData4], ['fifth', GetData5] ];


var PieChartPlot = $.jqplot('PieChart', [PieChartS1, PieChartS2], {
 seriesDefaults: {
    renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
    rendererOptions:{
    sliceMargin: 1,
    startAngle: -145,
    showDataLabels: true,
    dataLabels: 'label',
    padding: '5',
    ringMargin: '5',
    dataLabelThreshold: '1',
    highlightMouseOver: true,
  }   
},
grid: {background: 'transparent', borderWidth: '0', cursor: 'pointer',},

});
 });
```

I have drawn up a jsfiddle to show how it is currently working.

http://jsfiddle.net/6x82om3x/10/

This code is wrapped in a jquery .load() function that loads the right table row from an file into the page at the specified div ID, then the data is called from that. I have left this out for simplicity in the JS fiddle. I am aware I don't need the second tr call with the td call normally but did for the jsfiddle example.

I need to be able to just vary the file call and then the table ID for each chart, without of course affecting any of the others as they may also be on the same page in some situations.

Having trouble implementing this, so any helps would be appreciated

Thanks

Richard

Just been making an attempt. I think it would be something along these lines jsfiddle.net/6x82om3x/12

Comment: Just been making an attempt. I think it would be something along these lines http://jsfiddle.net/6x82om3x/12/

Comment: please specify exactly which parts you expect to be dynamic?